# Sci-Fi - House gets transported to space with brothers (possibly older sister) in it

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

From what little I remember of the movie and book, there was essentially a pair of brothers (one short and fat, the other taller and leaner) whose house gets transported to space (somehow.) They survive until an astronaut comes and saves them.

In the movie adaption, there was also an older sister who gets frozen at one point, and the brothers thaw her with a hairdryer or a lighter (using a blowtorch was shot down, as the younger brother kindly states that "You're gonna cook her." )

I distinctly remember a scene from the book where the fatter brother was, for whatever reason, expanding sideways and shrinking down, so the other brother had to do something to stop it.

They also might have had something to do with a board game (little brother was holding a board game while he was bloating, or maybe playing a board game during that time.)

Comment: This has been marked as a Duplicate, but please be assured that this is not a judgment on your question, merely  a bookkeeping thing we do on the site.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: If @arya hadn't told the answer, I would have said that it was most probably Phineas and Ferb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this might be Zathura: A Space Adventure, a 2005 movie.

Two brothers are playing a board game that affects reality, and is themed to outer space.

> Walter and Danny Budwing are two brothers who do not get along with each other or with their teenage sister, Lisa. While their divorced father is away at work and Lisa, whom he left in charge, is napping, Danny discovers an old space-themed board game called Zathura in the basement. When he starts playing, the game produces a card that summons a meteor shower inside the living room. Walter and Danny realize playing the game affects reality. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Zathura: A Space Adventure (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura:_A_Space_Adventure)*</sup></sub>

Their older sister is cryogenically frozen.

> The boys discover the house is floating in space. Lisa, thinks she has overslept and it is evening and prepares to go out. The next card puts her in cryonic sleep, leaving her frozen solid. Walter concludes they must win the game to return everything to normal. As they continue to play, Walter and Danny overcome the dangers presented by the game cards, including the appearance of a defective robot, passing too close to a star, and an attack on the house by a race of reptilian aliens called Zorgons. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Zathura: A Space Adventure (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura:_A_Space_Adventure)*</sup></sub>

The plot is that they found a board game that causes their house to be floating in space, so there is certainly a board game involved.

Comment: Yep, this is it! I forgot about the importance of the board game; this movie was a sort of Jumanji spin-off, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @AndroidWonKenobi Yes Zathura is a spin-off of Jumanji in that both films are adaptations of books; the Zathura book was written as a spin-off of the Jumanji book, both books written by the same author.